# How do I delete the text after &fbclid

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I want to delete out not only what I highlight in the image below, but all of content that's next to the word `&fbclid`

[image]

Here's an example of the current data:

| Field |
| --- |
| ISM1901&fbclid=IwAR2z5qnwcUyfM-lkWnpZ3xEAxqKiHUNzMhOgk1FaGlUNRhj0JmG0NPbR6Dg |
| MC001&fbclid=IwAR35725LxQW1N-m49Us0UOEDD7DFRJ9Aamu0O7KFJr5bL5CkxKyo9SW491Q |

Here's the expected result:

| Field |
| --- |
| ISM1901 |
| MC001 |

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT( Your_Field, '(.*)&fbclid=.*' )
```